# How do I modify the route parameters sent as props with React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I have a React `Router` with routes like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path='/' component={App} />
  <Route path='/:fileType/:fileId' component={App} />
</Router>
```

This puts props into my `App` like so:

```
{
  fileType: 'whatever', 
  fileId: 'ABC5734'
}
```

However, I have designed my component so that it expects this format:

```
{
  file: {
    type: 'whatever', 
    id: 'ABC5734'
  }
}
```

I would therefore like to transform the path props before they are sent to the component. Something like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path='/' component={App} />
  <Route 
    path='/:fileType/:fileId' 
    component={(props) => <App file={{type: props.fileType, id: props.fileId}} />} />
</Router>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-router sends route params under `this.props.params`. So, correct your your code.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path='/' component={App} />
  <Route 
    path='/:fileType/:fileId' 
    component={(props) => <App file={{type: props.params.fileType, id: props.params.fileId}} />} />
</Router>
```

Comment: `(props) => <App file={{type: props.params.fileType, id: props.params.fileId}} />` is itself a dumb component, having App component as child component.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Higher-Order Component.

You could use the [`mapProps`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#mapprops) Higher-order Component from [`recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/tree/master/src/packages/recompose) :

```
import mapProps from 'recompose/mapProps'

<Router history={history}>
  <Route path='/' component={App} />
  <Route 
    path='/:fileType/:fileId' 
    component={mapProps(({ params: { fileType, fileId } }) => ({
        fileType,
        fileId
    }))(App)}/>
</Router>
```